# Font awesome 0x0

Tags: javascript, css

Included the script

```
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
```

And in the code

```
   <span class="fas fa-chevron-down" style="float:right;"></span>
```

But I cant able to access font awesome icon . Its shows 0x0 [image: )x)]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The script you've included is Bootstrap, not Font Awesome. You need the Font Awesome style sheet. I suggest going to their [website](https://fontawesome.com/) to find instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CDN, and paste this link tag in between your head tags.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
```